# Fonts still missing in Flash after cleaning caches

Tags: macos, fonts, cache, adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

I was having a problem with missing fonts in Flash CS4, so I cleaned the font caches using the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
atsutil server -shutdown
atsutil server -ping
```

These commands ran fine, so I restarted and opened my Flash file. Now suddenly Verdana is missing in Flash which was previously there.

- I ran FontNuke, and cleaned caches, and rebooted. Still nothing showed in Flash.
- I ran Cocktail, and cleaned just the font caches (all users on system), still nothing in Flash.
- I reinstalled Flash (didn't work)
- I then uninstalled Flash, rebooted and installed Flash, rebooted. (didn't work)

After all this, Verdana still doesn't load in Flash. I validated all fonts in *Font Book* and removed the erroneous fonts.

Is there any other way I can have all the fonts load in Flash (eliminate another cache I am not seeing)? I am so sick of Flash and its font caches and *Verdana* is pretty much a standard font so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the answer lies: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2558650#2558650

It is a nuisance doing it this way, but it was the ONLY method that worked for me.

1. Firstly, close Flash.
2. **Move** all fonts from /Library/Fonts & ~/Library/Fonts to a folder on your desktop.
3. Start up Flash again, try opening the file which uses the missing fonts. (You should get the Font Replacement dialog now), click Cancel.
4. Quit Flash.
5. **Move** the .ttf/.otf files of the missing fonts (missing in Flash) back to /Library/Fonts, but only them, not the rest.
6. Start Flash up again with the .fla in question, your fonts should all be found now and render.
7. Quit Flash, move the rest of the font files back to /Library/Fonts (did not test it with User fonts i.e. ~/Library/Fonts, I suppose it would be just same copying them back to ~/Library/Fonts)
8. Open Flash again and all missing fonts should now be visible in Flash.

This is the **ONLY** method that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps specified by Adobe?

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/167/tn_16763.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am running Snow Leopard, and those files can't be found anywhere, or anywhere I am looking rather... Do you know where they are located, as the images on Adobe's website don't show up?

Comment: I Googled a Snow Leopard solution but couldn't find anything more recent on Adobe's site. Apparently the 10.0.2 update for Flash CS4 fixes this. Do you have this installed?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also thought that would fix it, so I installed that first.

Comment: Alas, my problems are still present in Flash. I don't know anymore ways on how to fix this.

Comment: I see you have found a solution. The other option is to contact Adobe, since they are the vendor and as you paid for their product you are entitled to a degree of support.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 font management applications (trying to clear system and Adobe font caches), it was fixed. I tried:

1. FontNuke
2. Font Finagler
3. Cocktail
4. FontExplorer Pro

Finally, FontExplorer Pro was the one that came through for me.

Conclusion: **I hate Flash**

Comment: Sad to say, but FontExplorer Pro did not return all the fonts.